# using keycodes to trigger events

Tags: javascript, keyup, character-codes

I'm using the following code to detect a key being pressed:

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) { // the event variable contains the key pressed            
    if (event.which == x+65) { 
        alert(numToChar(x));
    }
});
```

"B" is keycode 66; however, it fires when i press "b", and alerts 66, which is the capital B keycode.  little 'b' should alert "98"

I tried this in both firefox, and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

change the event to keypress if you want case sensitive keycodes.

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) { // the event variable contains the key pressed
   if (event.which == x+65) { 
      alert(numToChar(x));
   }
});
```